# Which version of LLVM and XCode do I need to use Array Literal Syntax in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, llvm

I'm running a training session which will teach beginner programmers how to code in Objective-C. With the new `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` literal syntax, it's a slightly less daunting task than it would've been.
However, I've been told that I will be restricted to using OS X Lion.

Does the latest version of XCode that works on Lion (4.2) support using the `@[@"one", @"two"]` syntax? Or do I have to use a newer version?

Thanks.

Comment: Xcode 4.6 is the latest version that runs on Lion so you can take advantage of the array literal syntax on Lion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for literals began in XCode 4.4 as per [this handy Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012243).

@YES/@NO literals have some additional requirements.

The introduction of Apple's [LLVM Compiler version 4.0](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) provides this feature.

Comment: +1 Correct. It may also be worth mentioning that these literals were added in Apple LLVM 4.0

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Not the answer I was hoping for, but at least I have an answer ;)

Comment: @0x7fffffff Thanks, I've added this to the answer as it does explain what changed in 4.4.

Comment: @MaxWoolf At least you can explain how literals work, and how they are actually implemented. There are still plenty of uses for the class & instance methods, of course.

Comment: @DavidCaunt Indeed, it's not a total disaster. Just `@[@"Hello"]` is a bit easier to explain than `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Hello", nil];`

Comment: it's also worth noting that the open source version of clang supports literals since v3.1

Answer (score 2):

Yes this support start from  Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0 with XCode 4.4 http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html this documentation give you most description information.